# Stick C app to all desktops

Tags: x11, xlib

I wrote a simple resource display program, that displays in a very small window some stats, like amount of free RAM. I want it to be visible on any desktop when I switch between them, how to achieve that?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to [n.m.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m) I am on the right track (hopefully), here is what I have got so far:

```
unsigned int ints[2];
ints[0] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
ints[1] = 2;
XChangeProperty(d, w, XInternAtom(d, "_NET_WM_DESKTOP", 1),
            XA_ATOM,
            32,
            PropModeReplace,
            (unsigned char*)ints,
            2);
```

It compiles, but it does not do anything, i.e. the window is still only visible on the desktop it was originally started. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

X11 or Xlib by themselves have no notion of desktops or switching between desktops. It's all in your window manager. Usually a window informs the WM about it needs through [window properties](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XChangeProperty.html).

Modern Freedesktop-compliant window managers use [_NET_WM_DESKTOP](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#idm45717752012480) property. Set it to `0xFFFFFFFF` before mapping the window.

> A Client MAY choose not to set this property, in which case the Window Manager SHOULD place it as it wishes. `0xFFFFFFFF` indicates that the window SHOULD appear on all desktops.

**Edit** the correct incantation is

```
unsigned long prop = 0xFFFFFFFF; // note long! even if long is 64 bit

XChangeProperty(d, w, XInternAtom(d, "_NET_WM_DESKTOP", 1),
                XA_CARDINAL, // note CARDINAL not ATOM
                32,
                PropModeReplace,
                (unsigned char*)&prop,
                1); // note 1

XMapWindow(d, w); // map after changing the property
```

You can use the `xprop` command line utility to verify that the property is set correctly.

Comment: In latest Ubuntu X11 headers  `_NET_WM_DESKTOP` is not even declared anywhere, cannot find a numeric equivalent anywhere too.

Comment: @exebook It's not supposed to be declared, it's a string, You call `XInternAtom(display, "_NET_WM_DESKTOP", False)`. Google this invocation.

Comment: can you see my updated question? Cannot get it right.

Comment: @exebook I have added a complete example